# Saving data into database using create function laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am having trouble saving this into database. When I submit my data into database it will only show name_of_bear and all the many relationship stuff(type_of_fish) but not the type_of_bear

Can someone explain to me why it can't work and also maybe give me an example on how it should be done. Thank you

Controller: (this works)

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
    $fishType= $request->input('type_of_fish');
    $Name = $request->input('Name');
    $bearType = $request->input('bearType');

    $bear = Bear::create(['Name' => $request->input('name_of_bear')]);
    $bear->fishs()->create(['type_of_fish' => json_encode($fishType)]);

    return ('thank you');

}
```

But if I were to do this:

Controller : (doesn't work)

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
    $fishType= $request->input('type_of_fish');
    $Name = $request->input('Name');
    $bearType = $request->input('bearType');

    $bear = Bear::create(['Name' => $Name]);
    $bear = Bear::create(['bearType' => $bearType]); --> doesn't  work if add in this
    $bear->fishs()->create(['type_of_fish' => json_encode($fishType)]);

    return ('thank you');

}
```

or this:

Controller: (doesn't work)

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
    $fishType= $request->input('type_of_fish');
    $Name = $request->input('Name');
    $bearType = $request->input('bearType');

    $bear = Bear::create(['Name' => $Name], ['bearType' => $bearType]); --> doesn't work
    $bear->fishs()->create(['type_of_fish' => json_encode($fishType)]);

    return ('thank you');

}
```

Comment: try `$bear = Bear::create(['Name' => $Name , 'bearType' => $bearType]);`

Comment: there is another way to inserting data to data base if you need i can share it with you

Comment: @Jigar Yup it works thanks a lot. Sure I would love to know more about it (to Gaurav)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it like this

```
$bear = Bear::create(['Name' => $Name , 'bearType' => $bearType]);
```

full code:

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
    $fishType= $request->input('type_of_fish');
    $Name = $request->input('Name');
    $bearType = $request->input('bearType');

    $bear = Bear::create(['Name' => $Name , 'bearType' => $bearType]);
    return ('thank you');
} // removed extra }
```

For further information you can read [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)

Comment: Tks but the documentation I had read it already and I find it a little difficult to understand. Is there possibly another resource where they would give more examples?

Comment: Yes there may be , you just need to google with specific topic. You can accept as answer if found useful :) .

Comment: $bear = Bear::create(['Name' => $Name , 'bearType' => $bearType]); is there any limit in using this? Because when I try add another field example $bear = Bear::create(['Name' => $Name, bearType=> $bearType, 'bearLocation' => $bearLocation]); it only show name and type and not the location in the database

Comment: Oh nvm I forgot to put protected fillable inside my model hahaha tks :)

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

`$bear = Bear::create(['Name' => $Name, 'bearType' => $bearType]);`

For more info, [visit this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Answer (score 1):

You can insert data like this:

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
    $data = array();
    $data['type_of_fish']= $request->type_of_fish;
    $data['Name'] = $request->Name;
    $data['bearType'] = $request->bearType;

    $bear = Bear::create($data);

    return ('thank you');

}
```

For more information read [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this, assuming that post array keys matches column names.

```
$bear = Bear::create($request->all()->except(['_token', 'type_of_fish']));
```